# Replace time points using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

My data frame looks like this

```
value <- c(0,0.1,0.2,0.4,0,0.05,0.05,0.5,0.20,0.40,0.50,0.60)
time <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)

test <- data.frame(value, time, ID)
test

   value time ID
1   0.00    1  1
2   0.10    1  2
3   0.20    1  3
4   0.40    1  4
5   0.00    2  1
6   0.05    2  2
7   0.05    2  3
8   0.50    2  4
9   0.20    3  1
10  0.40    3  2
11  0.50    3  3
12  0.60    3  4
```

In this example, my time series starts from '1' and ends to '3'. I want to replace the column 'time' and my time series to start from '0' and end to '2'. I would like my time series to look like this

```
   value time ID
1   0.00    0  1
2   0.10    0  2
3   0.20    0  3
4   0.40    0  4
5   0.00    1  1
6   0.05    1  2
7   0.05    1  3
8   0.50    1  4
9   0.20    2  1
10  0.40    2  2
11  0.50    2  3
12  0.60    2  4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
test %>%
  mutate(time = time - min(time))
#    value time ID
# 1   0.00    0  1
# 2   0.10    0  2
# 3   0.20    0  3
# 4   0.40    0  4
# 5   0.00    1  1
# 6   0.05    1  2
# 7   0.05    1  3
# 8   0.50    1  4
# 9   0.20    2  1
# 10  0.40    2  2
# 11  0.50    2  3
# 12  0.60    2  4
```

Using `time-min(time)` will always ensure that the first time is `0`, even if it does not start at `1`.

Comment: `time - time[1]` may be faster if it is already arranged

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `match` :

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% mutate(time = match(time, unique(time)) - 1)

#   value time ID
#1   0.00    0  1
#2   0.10    0  2
#3   0.20    0  3
#4   0.40    0  4
#5   0.00    1  1
#6   0.05    1  2
#7   0.05    1  3
#8   0.50    1  4
#9   0.20    2  1
#10  0.40    2  2
#11  0.50    2  3
#12  0.60    2  4
```

This would be helpful when you have a discontinuous timeseries like 1, 3, 4. Using `match` it will arrange it in 0, 1, 2.